# why use wireshark capture a c# ssl server/client program got TCP package?

Tags: c#, ssl, wireshark

I have write a ssl server/client program:

server:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root); 
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite); 
    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TestServer", false); 
    var x509 = certs[0]; 

    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.97.2"), 2000); 
    listener.Start(); 

    while (true) 
    { 
      var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); 
      var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false); 
      sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(x509, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true); 
      Console.WriteLine(ReadMessage(sslStream)); 
    }     
}
```

client:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
  var client = new TcpClient("192.168.97.2",2000); 
  var ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null); 
  ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("TestServer"); 
  byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc"); 
  ssl.Write(message); 
  ssl.Flush(); 
  client.Close(); 
}
```

it work's fine,but when I try to capture network packages by wireshark,I got TCP package between server and client.

I think I should got TLS package,I don't know why.

Comment: TCP is wrapping TLS here, not the other way around

Comment: BTW, you have to capture the whole SSL/TLS conversation so that Wireshark can better identify the stream via SSL/TLS handshakes. Otherwise, such packets are like random data over TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SSL handshake is in application layer not TCP/IP layer

and as you know wireshark monitors TCP/IP layer, So you can see Tcp process of handshake with some ambiguous data because it is encrypted with SSL public or private key.
So you can not monitor exact SSL handshake process with Wireshark(Although I work so many time with SSL I can not find any tools for monitoring exactly ssl handshake process).
good luck.